# How to convert "Jan_2015" character date in R dataframe to date format like 01JAN2015 or any other dateformat

Tags: r, lubridate

I have dates in character format in a dateframe as "Jan_2021". I need to convert these into dateformat like 01JAN2021 or MMDDYYYY format or any dateformat.

i am using below code to do it but not much success. Please help

```
'''Raw_data$Dmonth <- strptime(Raw_data$Dmonth, format = %b%Y)'''
```

Comment: use `lubridate::my("Jun_2021")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `zoo`'s `as.yearmon`.

```
val <- 'Jan_2021'
as.Date(zoo::as.yearmon(val, '%b_%Y'))
#[1] "2021-01-01"
```

Or in base R :

```
as.Date(paste0(val, '_1'), '%b_%Y_%d')
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `lubridate`

```
myd(val, truncated = 1)
#[1] "2021-01-01"
```

#### data

```
val <- 'Jan_2021'
```